# Find CheckBox state - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How can i find the state of the checkbox in laravel ? I want to perform a request based on the state of the checkbox. This what i am doing currently.

but then only the else part of the code keeps running. What am i doing wrong?

```
if(Input::get('check', false))                  
{                
    //do this
}
else 
{
    //do that             
}
```

**update**

```
$test = new Test(array(            

             'id' => $no,
             $checkbox = $request['myCheck'] ? 1 : 0;

                 if ($checkbox == 1) 
                 {
                   $set_amt= $label- $figure;

                 } else {
                   $set_amt = $get_all;

                 }
             'amount' => $amount,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in your controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $checkbox = $request['check'] ? 1 : 0;

    if ($checkbox == 1) 
    {
        //
    } else {
        //
    }
}
```

And in your view you make it like this:

```
{!! Form::label('check', 'Checkbox Label: ')!!}
{!! Form::check('check', null, isset($model_name) ? $model_name->check : 0, ['class' => 'form-control' ]) !!}
```

And if you don't use Form facade then in view do this:

```
<label for="check">Checkbox Label: </label>
<input class="form-control"
       value="1"
       name="check"
       type="checkbox"
       @if(isset($model) && $model->check == 1) checked @endif
>
```

#### Update

I don't know what did you want to achieve so I am only guessing now:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $checkbox = $request['myCheck'] ? 1 : 0;

    // I can't see in your code what are these so I just 
    // guessed that they are maybe part of $request:
    $set_amt = null;
    $label = $request['label'];
    $figure = $request['figure'];
    $get_all = $request['get_all'];

    if ($checkbox == 1) 
    {

       $set_amt = $label - $figure;

    } else {

       $set_amt = $get_all;

    }

    $test = new Test([            
             'id' => $no,
             'set_amt' => $set_amt,
             'amount' => $amount
         ]);

    $test->save();

    return redirect('/your_route_name');
}
```

Comment: how do i use this in an if statement?

Comment: Updated answer... if you need more help just write in comments.

Comment: kindly update your view to html. I don't use php forms and also i am getting a syntax error here  `$checkbox = $request['check'] ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: OK just a minute. And for that error you must have the $request in your function and then try to dd($request->all()) and see what is the name of your checkbox and put that name in this: `$checkbox = $request['checkbox_name'] ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: that is what i have done. i have $request there. look at my update

Comment: i get the error `syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'`

Comment: Me too because i never did this without Form facade... I am trying still to get this fixed... I will update my answer as soon as i fix this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159289/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-xamarindevil).

Comment: Can you check it now

Comment: did you check my update, because the syntax error is still showing

Comment: That is written very bad...you have a lot of errors... you are making an array and then inside you have ";" that is not allowed !